# Vector way of populating numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have some binary string `s` like `001010`. I want to convert it to numpy array `a` where `a[i] = np.array([[1], [0]])` if `s[i] == '0'` and to `np.array([[0], [1]])` otherwise.

So I wrote such code:

```
a = np.empty([len(s), 2, 1])
for i, char in enumerate(s):
    if char == '0':
        a[i] = np.array([[1], [0]])
    elif char == '1':
        a[i] = np.array([[0], [1]])
```

Can it be rewritten to a vectorized form without for-loop in a more numpy way?

My expected output looks like:

```
array([[[1.],
        [0.]],

       [[1.],
        [0.]],

       [[0.],
        [1.]],

       [[1.],
        [0.]],

       [[0.],
        [1.]],

       [[1.],
        [0.]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do so is by creating a `list` from the string, and then turn this list to a `np.array` of integers by specifying `dtype=int`:

```
s = '001010'

a = np.array(list(s), dtype=int)
# array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

And then use `np.where` in order to select among `np.array([[1], [0]])` or `np.array([[0], [1]])` according to the values in `a`:

```
np.where(a==0, np.array([[1], [0]]), np.array([[0], [1]])).T[:,:,None]
array([[[1],
        [0]],

       [[1],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [1]],

       [[1],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [1]],

       [[1],
        [0]]])
```

Comment: Actually OP wanted an array of arrays, but still +1 because I think, this is what he actually meant

Comment: Hmm not anymore after seing OPs update. Willl have to change

Comment: sorry, could you look to updated version of the question?

Comment: Updated the answer @RomaKarageorgievich. Let me know if this is what you want. Otherwise please share expected output

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich updated to match expected output

Answer (score 5):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one with NumPy char array -

```
sa = np.frombuffer(s,dtype='S1')
out = np.where(sa[:,None,None]=='0',[[1],[0]],[[0],[1]])
```

**Approach #2 :** One more as one-liner -

```
((np.frombuffer(s,dtype=np.uint8)[:,None]==[48,49])[...,None]).astype(float)
```

**Approach #3 :** Final one focused entirely on performance -

```
a = np.zeros([len(s), 2, 1])
idx = np.frombuffer(s,dtype=np.uint8)-48
a[np.arange(len(idx)),idx] = 1
```

Timings on a string of `100000` chars  -

```
In [2]: np.random.seed(0)

In [3]: s = ''.join(map(str,np.random.randint(0,2,(100000)).tolist()))

# @yatu's soln
In [4]: %%timeit
     ...: a = np.array(list(s), dtype=int)
     ...: np.where(a==0, np.array([[1], [0]]), np.array([[0], [1]])).T[:,:,None]
10 loops, best of 3: 36.3 ms per loop

# App#1 from this post    
In [5]: %%timeit
     ...: sa = np.frombuffer(s,dtype='S1')
     ...: out = np.where(sa[:,None,None]=='0',[[1],[0]],[[0],[1]])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.56 ms per loop

# App#2 from this post    
In [6]: %timeit ((np.frombuffer(s,dtype=np.uint8)[:,None]==[48,49])[...,None]).astype(float)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop

# App#3 from this post    
In [7]: %%timeit
     ...: a = np.zeros([len(s), 2, 1])
     ...: idx = np.frombuffer(s,dtype=np.uint8)-48
     ...: a[np.arange(len(idx)),idx] = 1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop
```